# How do I create a red box around a required radio button to appear when it's not selected after hit Send?

Tags: css, forms, colors, radio-button, required

I have some required radio buttons, but when the user didn't select them, and clicks on Send, I would like to have a red box around those buttons to alert them they've missed them. 
How can I do that?

There are no options in Formidable Forms

I expect the output to be a red box around the buttons.

Comment: show us what you tried so far or at least a picture

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **required** keyword in your input tag. If you want to change the default way of its appearance. You can refer following URL https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/required/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This will be my plan B, as far as I understand, every answer needs to be in the code. And our surveys are long and can change during the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation, if else statements and hide/show function to do that. 
 1. create a red box or rectangle over the radio buttons and hide it.
 2. set user validation
 3. use set visibility:visible to the red box on the required radio buttons which user did not select

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I have no idea how to create a red box over the radio buttons?

Comment: You can create an empty div, apply css (div background color: red, width and height to create a box and then use positioning to shift it to the radio button)